# Is there any method to embed Staticman comment system in non-jekyll site?

Tags: javascript, html, comments, github-pages

I hosted my website hosted on Github as Github pages without using any static site generators (example: Jekyll).
I created my own HTML webpage with my own design and code which I have hosted my webpage as Github pages.
I was wondering that, Is there any way to integrate or embed Staticman comment system directly in my HTML page as that same HTML page is hosted on Github.
Thank you,
Karunakar Pate Blog (https://www.alltechnotricks.com).

Comment: This is cross-posted on GitHub: https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman/issues/295.  Please make this clear so that we won't duplicate efforts.  To respond to your question in the title, yes, refer to any Hugo (i.e. non-Jekyll) theme that supports Staticman.

Comment: Btw, here's [my reply to your comment](https://staticman-gitlab-pages.frama.io/hyde-hyde-demo/posts/hugoisforlovers/#comment-1r1).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a broad question.  You might want to add details on what you have already done and what roadblocks you are running into.

Have you tried the steps in their README?
https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman#setting-up-a-repository

Also, you should check out this:
https://mademistakes.com/articles/improving-jekyll-static-comments/

Comment: I hosted my website on Github as Github pages with my own custom design and code. 
Here it is how I designed my webpage. 
<html> <head><title>some title</title></head><body> Total Article & imp tags, div goes here. </body></html>
That's it, no short codes, no js or jquery. 
I was wondering how to integrate staticman comments using HTML or Javascript etc. directly in the HTML webpage.

Comment: The official Staticman docs has become outdated. The user @staticmanapp no longer exists, as reported in https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman/issues/306.